# For ssh connection, getting error "Failed to load key ----, invalid format, Permission denied (publickey)" in Anaconda, Windows

Tags: windows, ssh, anaconda

Using Anaconda prompt in Windows I get this problem. Using latest version of ssh.

Answer (score 0):

Public and private key files were not in unix format. For Powershell, it seems fine but for both Anaconda prompts (normal and Powershell) this was a problem. You can use notepad++ or some other program (ex: dos2unix) to convert them to unix format. For notepad++, you can click on the format (Windows CR LF) to change it into Unix.